# Node.innerHTML giving tag names in lower case

Tags: javascript, dojo, innerhtml

I am iterating **NodeList** to get **Node** data, but while using **Node.innerHTML** i am getting the tag names in lowercase.

*Actual Tags*

```
<Panel><Label>test</Label></Panel>
```

*giving as*

```
<panel><label>test</label></panel>
```

I need these tags as it is. Is it possible to get it with regular expression? I am using it with dojo (is there any way in dojo?).

```
var xhrArgs = {
            url: "./user/"+Runtime.userName+"/ws/workspace/"+Workbench.getProject()+"/lib/custom/"+(first.type).replace(".","/")+".html",
            content: {},
            sync:true,
            load: function(data){
                var test = domConstruct.toDom(data);
                dojo.forEach(dojo.query("[id]",test),function(node){
                    domAttr.remove(node,"id");
                });
                var childEle = "";
                dojo.forEach(test.childNodes,function(node){
                    if(node.innerHTML){
                            childEle+=node.innerHTML;
                    }
                });
                command.add(new ModifyCommand(newWidget,{},childEle,context));
            }
    };
```

Comment: What is "it"? Can't you just use the *i* (case insensitive) flag with your expression? In HTML, tag name case is irrelevant. Browsers will usually present tag names as all upper or all lower case, but that's just an observation. Oh, and regular expressions aren't very good for parsing markup. Oh, if you call it XML, browsers should preserve case.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot count on `.innerHTML` preserving the exact nature of your original HTML.  In fact, in some browsers, it's significantly different (though generates the same results) with different quotation, case, order of attributes, etc...

It is much better to not rely on the preservation of case and adjust your javascript to deal with uncertain case.

It is certainly possible to use a regular expression to do a case insensitive search (the "i" flag designates its searches as case insensitive), though it is generally much, much better to use direct DOM access/searching rather than innerHTML searching.  You'd have to tell us more about what exactly you're trying to do before we could offer some code.

Comment: Hi jfriend00, I attached my code, where i need tags as it is because i am using them somewhere else to generate xml. ModifyCommand need text as children. so that it will place the data inside widget.

Answer (score 0):

It would take me a bit to figure that out with a regex, but you can use this:

```
    var str = '<panel><label>test</label></panel>';
    chars = str.split("");
    for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        if (chars[i] === '<' || chars[i] === '/') {
           chars[i + 1] = chars[i + 1].toUpperCase();
        }
    }
    str = chars.join("");
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chris6334/JwsT4/8/)

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to just capitalise the first character of the tag name, you can use:

```
var s = 'panel';
s.replace(/(^.)(.*)/,function(m, a, b){return a.toUpperCase() + b.toLowerCase()}); // Panel
```

Alternatively you can use string manipulation (probably more efficient than a regular expression):

```
s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1).toLowerCase(); // Panel
```

The above will output any input string with the first character in upper case and everything else lower case.

Answer (score 0):

this is not thoroughly tested , and is highly inefficcient, but it worked quite quickly in the console:
(also, it's jquery, but it can be converted to pure javascript/DOM easily)

[in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CnuFh/)

```
function  tagString (element) {
    return $(element).
            clone().
            contents().
            remove().
            end()[0].
            outerHTML.
            replace(/(^<\s*\w)|(<\/\s*\w(?=\w*\s*>$))/g,
                    function (a) {
                        return a.
                               toUpperCase();
                    }).
            split(/(?=<\/\s*\w*\s*>$)/);
}

function capContents (element) {
    return $(element).
            contents().
            map(function () { 
                   return this.nodeType === 3 ? $(this).text() : capitalizeHTML(this);
            })
}

function capitalizeHTML (selector) {
    var e = $(selector).first();
    var wrap = tagString(e);
    return wrap[0] + capContents(e).toArray().join("") + wrap[1];
}

capitalizeHTML('body');
```

also, besides being a nice exercise (in my opinion), do you really need to do this?