# Save innerHTML case sensitive

Tags: javascript, html, xml, innerhtml

I'm using this script to save `innerHTML`:

```
function downloadInnerHtml1(filename, elId, mimeType) {
    var elHtml = document.getElementById(elId).innerHTML;
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    mimeType = mimeType || 'application/xhtml+xml';

    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    link.setAttribute('href', 'data:' + mimeType + ';charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(elHtml));
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}

var fileName1 = 'test_xml.xml';

function save_xml() {
    downloadInnerHtml1(fileName1, 'pohoda', 'application/xhtml+xml');
}
```

I'm exporting it as XML. Everything is good, but node names are not saved case sensitive. 
Original is `<offerHeader>`, but when i save it, it's lowercase . I need it as original, case sensitive.

Can anybody help me with this? Thanks in advance!

/edit: Same result in chrome and firefox.
I don't need capitalize only first paragraph.

Comment: What you get with innerHTML depends on the browser. If you want to work with XML, then use a proper parser, not innerHTML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.innerHTML giving tag names in lower case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074446/node-innerhtml-giving-tag-names-in-lower-case), [also this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17193511/1456376).

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: The problem is you are passing innerHTML in your url by calling encodeURIComponent(). This will become the original text into lowercase and use uppercases for escaping certain characters as hexadecimal values. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_encodeuricomponent

Comment: Tried to delete encodeURIComponent, but the same result. Can anybody tell me, what I need change? Or somebody with a better script for download XML from div?

Answer (score 0):

you can't use the innerHTML property because it serializes the HTML, and HTML tags are case-insensitive. Instead, you can use the `XMLSerializer` interface to create an XML string while preserving the case sensitivity of tags

```
function downloadInnerHtml1(filename, elId, mimeType) {
    var elHtml = document.getElementById(elId);
    var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
    var xmlString = serializer.serializeToString(elHtml);
    
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    mimeType = mimeType || 'application/xml';
    
    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    link.setAttribute('href', 'data:' + mimeType + ';charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(xmlString));
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}

var fileName1 = 'test_xml.xml';

function save_xml() {
    downloadInnerHtml1(fileName1, 'pohoda', 'application/xml');
}
```

`XMLSerializer` to serialize the XML content, which ensures that the case sensitivity of tags is preserved. The `downloadInnerXml` function takes care of creating a download link with the serialized XML content