# Case-sensitive .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to replace a tag using `.innerHTML`.

It looks like this:

```
var foo = document.getElementsByTagName("Foo");
for(var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
   foo[i].innerHTML = "<Bar>Lorem ipsum</Bar>";
}
```

However, since `.innetHTML` returns case-insensitive on Firefox and it's not consistant across web browers. I got

```
<bar>lorm ipsum</bar>
```

What should I do to get case-sensitive return? (Without using jQuery or too-complex code).

I have searched and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718091/alternative-for-innerhtml), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074446/node-innerhtml-giving-tag-names-in-lower-case?noredirect=1&lq=1), but those are 9 and 5 years old and not really answer what I need. So I think it'd be ok to ask this question again.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: <Bar> is not valid Html. You cannot put it inside. Why do you want a capital on your tag?

Comment: @ChrisR I just want to experiment with custom tags. I use custom tags for ease of style in CSS. (I know it sounds silly, but it's just a random thing to experiment.)

Comment: HTML tag names are simply not case-sensitive, so it doesn't matter. `<Bar>` and `<bar>` and `<BAR>` mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: Browsers are/were inconsistent with how they handle the case of unknown tag names, [fun read](https://johnresig.com/blog/nodename-case-sensitivity/).  Don’t rely on this technique.